# jquery click function element scrolling inside a div instead of html, body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have few group of `list` element inside a `div`. This `div` is scroll able. I have few link element for specify the list group. If user `click` on this specific link then `div` will `scroll` and specific list group will be `show` on `top` of the `div`.

Regular `scrollTop` `function` almost working. Main issue is targeted list group is targeting `html, body` not parent `div` `.language-list-alph`.

> Snippet is below.

```js
$(function(){
    $('.quick-lang-shorting .shorting-list li a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = this.hash;
        var $target = $(target);
        $('.language-list-alph').stop().animate({'scrollTop': $target.offset().top}, 1200);
    });
});
```

```css
*:after,
*:before{
  content: '';
  display: table;
}
*:after{
  clear: both;
}
*{
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 100px 30px 30px;
}
.translation-lang,
.quick-lang-shorting{
  display: block;
  float: left;
  min-height: 1px;
}
.translation-lang{
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 50px);
  width: -moz-calc(100% - 50px);
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
}
.language-list-alph{
  display: block;
  height: 600px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding-right: 17px;
  width: 100%;
}
.lang-list-group{
  list-style: inside none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.lang-list-group li{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #121212;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
.quick-lang-shorting{
  width: 50px;
}
.shorting-list{
  list-style: inside none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.shorting-list li{
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="translation-lang">
  <div class="language-list-alph">
    <ul class="lang-list-group" id="lang_list_group_a">
      <li>
        <span>Argentina</span>
      </li>
    </ul><!-- Language list group -->
    <ul class="lang-list-group" id="lang_list_group_b">
      <li>
        <span>Belgium</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Brasil</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Bulgaria</span>
      </li>
    </ul><!-- Language list group -->
    <ul class="lang-list-group" id="lang_list_group_c">
      <li>
        <span>Canada</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>China</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Ivory Coast</span>
      </li>
    </ul><!-- Language list group -->
    <ul class="lang-list-group" id="lang_list_group_d">
      <li>
        <span>Denmark</span>
      </li>
    </ul><!-- Language list group -->
    <ul class="lang-list-group" id="lang_list_group_e">
      <li>
        <span>Estonia</span>
      </li>
    </ul><!-- Language list group -->
    <ul class="lang-list-group" id="lang_list_group_f">
      <li>
        <span>France</span>
      </li>
    </ul><!-- Language list group -->
    <ul class="lang-list-group" id="lang_list_group_g">
      <li>
        <span>Greece</span>
      </li>
    </ul><!-- Language list group -->
    <ul class="lang-list-group" id="lang_list_group_h">
      <li>
        <span>Hungary</span>
      </li>
    </ul><!-- Language list group -->
    <ul class="lang-list-group" id="lang_list_group_i">
      <li>
        <span>India</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Ireland</span>
      </li>
    </ul><!-- Language list group -->
    <ul class="lang-list-group" id="lang_list_group_j">
      <li>
        <span>Ireland</span>
      </li>
    </ul><!-- Language list group -->
    <ul class="lang-list-group" id="lang_list_group_k">
      <li>
        <span>Argentina</span>
      </li>
    </ul><!-- Language list group -->
    <ul class="lang-list-group" id="lang_list_group_l">
      <li>
        <span>Argentina</span>
      </li>
    </ul><!-- Language list group -->
    <ul class="lang-list-group" id="lang_list_group_m">
      <li>
        <span>Argentina</span>
      </li>
    </ul><!-- Language list group -->
    <ul class="lang-list-group" id="lang_list_group_n">
      <li>
        <span>Argentina</span>
      </li>
    </ul><!-- Language list group -->
    <ul class="lang-list-group" id="lang_list_group_o">
      <li>
        <span>Argentina</span>
      </li>
    </ul><!-- Language list group -->
    <ul class="lang-list-group" id="lang_list_group_p">
      <li>
        <span>Argentina</span>
      </li>
    </ul><!-- Language list group -->
    <ul class="lang-list-group" id="lang_list_group_q">
      <li>
        <span>Argentina</span>
      </li>
    </ul><!-- Language list group -->
    <ul class="lang-list-group" id="lang_list_group_r">
      <li>
        <span>Argentina</span>
      </li>
    </ul><!-- Language list group -->
    <ul class="lang-list-group" id="lang_list_group_s">
      <li>
        <span>Argentina</span>
      </li>
    </ul><!-- Language list group -->
    <ul class="lang-list-group" id="lang_list_group_t">
      <li>
        <span>Argentina</span>
      </li>
    </ul><!-- Language list group -->
    <ul class="lang-list-group" id="lang_list_group_u">
      <li>
        <span>Argentina</span>
      </li>
    </ul><!-- Language list group -->
    <ul class="lang-list-group" id="lang_list_group_v">
      <li>
        <span>Argentina</span>
      </li>
    </ul><!-- Language list group -->
    <ul class="lang-list-group" id="lang_list_group_w">
      <li>
        <span>Argentina</span>
      </li>
    </ul><!-- Language list group -->
    <ul class="lang-list-group" id="lang_list_group_x">
      <li>
        <span>Argentina</span>
      </li>
    </ul><!-- Language list group -->
    <ul class="lang-list-group" id="lang_list_group_y">
      <li>
        <span>Argentina</span>
      </li>
    </ul><!-- Language list group -->
    <ul class="lang-list-group" id="lang_list_group_z">
      <li>
        <span>Argentina</span>
      </li>
    </ul><!-- Language list group -->
  </div><!-- Language list by alpha -->
</div><!-- Translation language -->
<div class="quick-lang-shorting">
  <ul class="shorting-list">
    <li><a href="#lang_list_group_a">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#lang_list_group_b">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="#lang_list_group_c">C</a></li>
    <li><a href="#lang_list_group_d">D</a></li>
    <li><a href="#lang_list_group_e">E</a></li>
    <li><a href="#lang_list_group_f">F</a></li>
    <li><a href="#lang_list_group_g">G</a></li>
    <li><a href="#lang_list_group_h">H</a></li>
    <li><a href="#lang_list_group_i">I</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">J</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">K</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">L</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">M</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">N</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">O</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">P</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Q</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">R</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">S</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">T</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">U</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">V</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">W</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">X</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Y</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Z</a></li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- Quick lang shorting -->
```

How can I target the `div` (`.language-list-alph`) instead of `html, body`?

> If any one want to edit this question it will be appreciate.

Comment: $('.language-list-alph').stop().animate... change to $('html, body').stop().animate({'scrollTop'

Comment: @arturmoroz did you read the question details clearly?

Comment: My target isn't `html, body`. My target is `.language-list-alph`.

Comment: You need to get position not from body, but from parent element?

Comment: $target.offset().top ==> $target.position().top

Comment: @arturmoroz Thanks. It's working now. Just one more change need in `CSS`. Need to add  `.language-list-alph{position: relative;}`